# ssh problems in buildfarm

Tags: ros-lunar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a continuation of [this post](https://answers.ros.org/question/297937/most-jobs-fail-in-my-buildfarm/). This is the error log from running lunar_rosdistro_cache job.

```
14:50:51 The command '/bin/sh -c python3 -u /tmp/wrapper_scripts/apt.py update-install-clean -q -y git python3-catkin-pkg-modules python3-rosdistro python3-yaml' returned a non-zero code: 100
14:50:51 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
14:50:51 SSH: Current build result is [FAILURE], not going to run.
```

I followed everything mentioned in the documentation. When I tried to test the connection in jenkins to the repo machine, the test configuration fails and sends me this error message.

```
Failed to connect or change directory
jenkins.plugins.publish_over.BapPublisherException: Failed to connect and initialize SSH connection. Message: [Failed to connect session for config [repo]. Message [Auth fail]]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298637/ssh-problems-in-buildfarm/) by [venkisagunner](https://answers.ros.org/users/29258/venkisagunner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 89 on 2018-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved the problem by adding a ssh host key for the jenkins-agent as mentioned below in the common.yaml file:

```
 'jenkins-agent@ip-address':
        key: AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAAC
        type: ssh-rsa
        user: jenkins-agent
        require: User[jenkins-agent]
```

---

Originally posted by [venkisagunner](https://answers.ros.org/users/29258/venkisagunner/) with karma: 89 on 2018-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1